# URL Regex / Helper / Recognizer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app that allows users to post, very similar to a forum. If a user types a link in, I want that link to become an  element when it is printed to the page. For example, pretend this was a user post:

```
"I love this new website www.newwebsite.com!"
```

I want the above string to be printed to the page as:

```
I love this new website <a href="www.newwebsite.com">www.newwebsite.com</a>
```

Are there any rails helpers, gems, or built-in modules to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) for this. If you're using a version of Rails prior to 3.1, this functionality is built-in and you don't need the gem.

Answer (score -1):

you may like to try out something this

```
<%= auto_link(simple_format(word_wrap(@content,:line_width => 75)), :html => { :target => '_blank' }) -%>
```

more about these text helpers here -> http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html